# Calculation of the integral does not occur

Tags: definite-integrals, matlab

It is necessary to calculate the a definite integral of the probability distribution function:

\begin{align}
I &= \int\limits_{\xi=-\infty}^{-1} \frac{\mu \, d\xi}{2 \cdot (1+\mu^2 \cdot ((\xi-m) \cdot k)^2)^{3/2}}.
\end{align}

```
syms psii mu m ku
f = mu./(2.*(1+mu.^2.*((psii-m)*ku).^2).^(3/2));
P2 =int(f, psii, -inf, -1)
```

Calculation of the integral does not occur.

Comment: It is so simple !

Comment: If you know, tell me why the calculation is not happening?

Comment: What is the antiderivative ? How do you want to be helped if you do not show your work. Using Matlab is **not** doing mathematics.

Comment: I can find a primitive one like this: P2 =int(f, psii)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the integrand $f(\xi)$

$$f(\xi )\text{=}\frac{\mu }{2 \left(\mu ^2 (k (\xi -m))^2+1\right)^{3/2}}$$

we will get the antiderivative

$$F(\xi )=\int f(\xi ) \, d\xi =\frac{\mu  (\xi -m)}{2 \sqrt{k^2 \mu ^2 (m-\xi )^2+1}}$$

Finally we treat the limits to calculate the definite integral

$$\int_{-\infty }^{-1} f(\xi ) \, d\xi =F(-1)-\underset{x\to -\infty }{\text{lim}}F(x)=\frac{1}{2} \mu  \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{k^2 \mu ^2}}-\frac{m+1}{\sqrt{k^2 \mu ^2 (m+1)^2+1}}\right)$$

Working MATLAB code:

```
syms xsi mu m k
f = mu/(2*(1+mu^2*((xsi-m)*k)^2)^(3/2));
F = int(f, xsi);
l1 = limit(F, xsi, -1);
l2 = limit(F, xsi, -inf);
result = l1 - l2;
```

Comment: I suggest you do not answer this kind of question which does not show any work from the OP.

Comment: Thank you very much, kind man. I find it strange that matlab does not calculate a certain integral immediately, but calculates if the limits are substituted manually